# . Use "DAVERAGE" function to calculate the average price of each product ?excell

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have following data

```
     6489   O-Ring   3.00 
     6431   O-Ring   2.85 
     6433   O-Ring   2.95 
     6321   O-Ring   2.45 
     8008   Machined 645.00 
     8148   Machined 655.50
```

I am using formula

```
   =DAVERAGE(D131:F134,E132,F131:F134)
```

But returns error   !DIV/0

i need the exact way to calculate the daverage of my values in list

[image]

Comment: see my answer below, you need to build your worksheet DB and result area accordingly for the `DAVERAGE` to give you what you want

Comment: have you tested the function in my answer below ? did it work for you ?

Answer (score 0):

Your values are text, not numeric, change them to numbers, i.e. enter 3, 2.85 in the top 2

Comment: `=DAVERAGE(D131:F134,"O-Ring",F131:F134)`  but error `#DIV/0!`

Comment: STILL PROBLEM THERE

Comment: The field you have "o-ring" in, is the name or index of the column you want to average, are you thinking of an average if function?

Comment: SEE IMAGE I HAVE ATTACHED

Comment: Read what I've written :)

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to add headers to your Database that you are trying to get the `Daverage` function to work on (see screen-shot below).

[image]

Then use the formula:

```
=DAVERAGE($D$131:$F$137,"Price",H131:H132)
```

With respective to the format in the screen-shot below (also your "criteria" need headers for the Comparison to work on, Columns H and I):

[image]